# Moved DevKit to a different directory. How do I make it work again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devkit

I know it said not to move it, but after I did `ruby dk.rb init` and `ruby dk.rb install` I moved it to a different directory because I didn't want it to clutter the directory it was in. I was able to `gem install json` before, but now when I try to test if it works by running `gem install json --platform=ruby` I get the following error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing json:
       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
     C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb

creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/jsln/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

reinstall.  from your console, go to the path where you now have the devkit

`D:\stuff\devkit`

`ruby dk.rb init` - then open up the `config.yml` file that lives in that directory... make sure it's pointing to your ruby installation

`ruby dk.rb install`

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit